# Selecting local files using watir-webdriver

Tags: ruby, automation, watir-webdriver, filefield

I'm attempting to automate the process of selecting a local file from a html page using watir-webdriver

I have the following html

```
<body>
<form method="post" action="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
test file to upload: <input type="file" name="file" size="60" id="test"/>
<input type="submit" value="Upload" name="upload" id="upload" />
</form>
</body>
```

I'm attempting to click the input with an `id` of `test` and set a path to the local file I wish to upload using watir-webdriver.

I can use the following to click the button to bring up the selection window using

```
@browser.goto 'http://www.test.com'
@browser.button(:id => 'test').click
```

however, i'm trying to use the following (from researching, this seems the correct way. not working though)

```
@browser.file_field(:name => 'file').set("C:\\path\\to\\test\\file\\validTest.xml")
```

which results in the following error

```
Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException: unable to locate element, using {:name=>"file",    :tag_name=>"input", :type=>"file"}
```

trying

```
@browser.button(:id => 'test').set("C:\\path\\to\\test\\file\\validTest.xml")
```

results in the following error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `set' for #<Watir::Button:0x3859920>
```

Can anyone help? I'm struggling to understand why the `file_field` option doesn't work.

Comment: If you're getting `UnknownObjectException`, then try `@browser.file_field(:name => 'file').exists?`.  If `false`, then it's possible the element isn't really locatable (e.g. in frame, loading asynchronously, etc.).  And the [`Button`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Button) class doesn't have a `.set` method, so that error is legitimate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the following function:

```
@browser.file_field(:id,"upload").set("filepath")
```

Also, if you are using IE browser then make sure you are using IEDriverServer_Win32_2.33.0 as it works fine on this driver not on latest one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@browser.file_field(:id => 'test').set("C:\\path\\to\\test\\file\\validTest.xml")
```

Comment: returns `Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException: unable to locate element, using {:id=>"test", :tag_name=>"input", :type=>"file"}`

Comment: @user3927287, ok, try this, also
`@browser.element(:xpath => '//input[@type="File"]')`

Comment: returns `NoMethodError: undefined method "set" for #<Watir::HTMLElement:0x38239c8>`

Comment: @user3927287, I'm sorry, this: `@browser.file_field(:xpath => '//input[@type="File"]')`

Comment: thanks for the quick replies: `@browser.file_field(:xpath => '//input[@type="File"]')` returns `Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException: unable to locate element, using {:xpath=>"//input[@type=\"File\"]", :tag_name=>"input", :type=>"file"}` and  `@browser.file_field(:xpath => '//input[@type="file"]')` returns `Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException: unable to locate element, using {:xpath=>"//input[@type=\"file\"]", :tag_name=>"input", :type=>"file"}` would the issue be with the HTML?

Comment: @user3927287, I don't think so, but, HTML that you send - 100% correct?

Comment: @user3927287, also, find this variant, `@browser.find_element(:name, "file").send_keys("C:\\path\\to\\test\\file\\validTest.xml")`

Answer (score 0):

Try using like this in latest IEDriver.
assign file path to variable  and then set it

```
filepath = "C:\\path\\to\\test\\file\\validTest.xml"
@browser.file_field(:id,"upload").set(filepath)
```